# Store data in SQLite at first app execution

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I wonder if it is possible to create a SQLite database when the app got run the first time and already save some data in it.

I don't want to save it every time the app gets started. Just after Installation.

Is this possible?

Comment: onCreate of SQLiteOpenHelper ?

Comment: is onCreate just called one time? Not always when app starts? When do i call it?

Comment: onCreate of **SQLiteOpenHelper**? yes, only if database not exists ... do not call it by yourself ... just `new SQLiteOpenHelperImpl().getWritableDatabase()`

Comment: so i call this in my MainActivity ? it will be called every time the app starts.

Comment: FSM save us! please go to http://d.android.com and find some database tutorial there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override `onCreate()` method in class which extends from SQLiteOpenHelper and insert there some data.

> Called when the database is created for the first time. This is where
>   the creation of tables and the initial population of the tables should
>   happen.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase) .

Answer (score 1):

For my apps I do the simple trick as in Splash check preference of available Data variable, first time its default is false. Then I read from Database and check is there any items If No then insert data and set preference available data variable  to true.
and when you come next time splash it will check again and in your available data variable will get true so you don't need to do anything and continue your flow.

I hope this will help you too :)

Answer (score 0):

[SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) should do the trick, simply compare `oldVersion` with `newVersion`